# Lightweight Communications Marshalling - lcm-spy is not displaying messaged published over lcm

Tags: lcm

I have lcm installed and running on a Ubuntu 18 computer and I can see my lcm messages displayed in the lcm-spy GUI. I recently installed lcm on a Ubuntu 22 computer using the commands: sudo apt-get install liblcm-dev and sudo apt install liblcm-bin. I also updated the class pass on the Ubuntu 22 computer to point to the correct lcm jar files. When I run lcm-spy the GUI opens but displays no lcm messages that are being published. Which the Ubuntu 18 computer is displaying. The terminal outputs of the Ubuntu 18 computer and the Ubuntu 22 computer are identical. I am not seeing any other error messages that could help point me to the cause. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can track down the issue?

I have tried looking at sys logs for additional error messages but did not see anything.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else who is also seeing this issue, we were running openjdk 8 on both of those computers but updating the ubuntu 22 computers to openjdk 11 resolved the issue.